# Waking up my computer every minute

Tags: windows, laptop, sleep, webcam

Gday.

I would like to set up my laptop, an Asus netbook w/o the "resume previous power state" feature my dell desktop has, to turn on when AC power is restored after a power loss.

In my particular scenario, power losses will be frequent and the laptop has to wake up whenever the power returns. The laptop will not be having a battery (built in) or UPS attached.

One way i was thinking, was to use the task scheduler to run a task every minute to wake up the PC if it's on AC power. I tried a task that starts at a time and then repeats every minute, (since run every minute wasnt an option in task scheduler), and that didn't wake up the computer from sleep. (in the real scenarion it would restart from off).

The OS for the laptop would be anything from win XP to 8, whatever is needed. Though win7 is already installed onto it.

I'm not limited to a laptop only, if neeeeed be, i could use a tablet (win rt or pro). The scenario is a computer with several webcams attached and a 7" usb powered touchscreen display. The purpose of it all is to fit 'surround cameras' to my car. So the tablet option would only work if it can drive the 7" display and lots of webcams through a powered hub. Though, i'd rather re-use my netbook.

So, each time the user turns the car off, the computer powers off. Each time they restart the computer starts and my camera app runs. The app will probably be made in .net as i'm quite familiar with that.

Thank you!

Comment: If the device doesn't have a "Power On after AC loss" option in the BIOS, then you're pretty much SOL.

Comment: I see. I had to urban dictionary SOL :D

Comment: Well, as it so happened; an old netbook I had which had a broken screen has a "feature" that if I press and hold the power button the computer turns on, and doesn't turn off! (if i keep the power button pressed). And then, if the power is removed, and then reconnected, it turns on again!

Hooray.

So I shall be hotwiring that to "ON" all the time and my solution is found.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7

(log in as an administrator if not already) 
Control panel -> power options

if there isn't a default plan there that does what you want it to (different resellers will include there own power plans such as "HP recommended" therefor it's hard to say what pre-configured options will display for you.  You can edit existing palns but you might also want to just create one from scratch.  There should be a "Create a Power Plan" link.  The option to sleep when AC power is removed is an easy pick off the basic screen.  The option to wake it up when power is restored is buried deeper:

Click "change Advanced Power Settings"
find "sleep" and expand it.
expand "Allow Wake Timers"
enable "plugged in"

Comment: For this to work, the laptop requires to have a battery installed, otherwise the instant power loss will cause the laptop to not even shutdown properly. I would not recommend crashing windows like this anyway. @Peter Pete: If you don't have a working battery, make sure you get one.

Comment: ohhhh... i missed this in his question: "The laptop will not be having a battery (built in) or UPS attached."  No you will have to have a battery, you won't be able to re-boot from power off state. and crashing windows like that is a really bad idea as mentioned just above =]

Comment: Yeah, no batt as it's pretty old